# Is this one way of estimating the size of compliers in instrumental variables analysis?

Tags: instrumental-variables

I have a continuous instrument that is strongly associated with the exposure.  I have also confirmed statistically that my selected instrument is strong and relevant.  My concern is with compliers.  I understand that under the monotonicity assumption, all four subgroups (i.e., compliers, defiers, always-takers, never-takers) cannot be distinguished since we are dealing with counterfactual scenarios.  However, would a strong association between the instrument and exposure be interpreted as my sample being composed mostly of compliers?